# Transparency of JLayeredPane in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to add an overlay to an Applet, displayed in a JFrame.

The Applet is on the content pane, while the overlay is on the JLayeredPane of the JFrame.

[Here's what it looks like visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwYT2.png)

The only thing happening that isn't shown, is that the addApplet() method is called once the Applet has been loaded and is ready to play.

I tried to disable all drawing in the JLayeredPane, yet it still draws the grey background that is visible. I don't know where that background is coming from.

Note that both of the colors are visible, so each PaintComponent must be transparent.

How do I get rid of the grey background?

```java
public class RuneFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel loadingLabel;
    private PaintComponent paintLayer1;
    private PaintComponent paintLayer2;

    public RuneFrame() {
        super("Rune");
        this.setSize(781, 542);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        loadingLabel = new JLabel("Loading...");
        loadingLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(loadingLabel);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an Applet to the frame. Do this when the applet has loaded.
     * @param applet    Game shown in this frame.
     */
    public void addApplet(Applet applet) {
        remove(loadingLabel);

        paintLayer1 = new PaintComponent(Color.yellow, new Color(0,0,0,0));
        this.getLayeredPane().add(paintLayer1, new Integer(1000));

        paintLayer2 = new PaintComponent(new Color(0,0,0,0), Color.red);
        this.getLayeredPane().add(paintLayer2, new Integer(1000));

        this.getLayeredPane().setOpaque(false);
        this.getLayeredPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        add(applet);
        pack();
    }
}
```

```java
public class PaintComponent extends JComponent {

    private Color c1;
    private Color c2;

    public PaintComponent(Color c1, Color c2) {
        super();
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;

        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        int w = 200;
        int h = 200;
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, h, c2));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: AWT components (like `Applet`) aren't capable of been transparent/translucent. The `paint` method of your `PaintComponent` should be calling `super.paint`, assuming you're expecting it to paint it's children

Comment: I'd also have a look at [How to use RootPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to see how the `JLayeredPane` is used by the `JFrame`

Comment: The `Applet` wont be transparent. It's in the back. The idea is that the Applet is drawn first - then the `PaintComponent` on top. That also explains why I'm not calling `super.paint`: I'm not interested in _anything_ else than the gradient.

EDIT: I read the documentation on `JRootPane` before posting. It says "You can choose to put components in the root pane's layered pane".

Comment: Okay, AWT components also don't have a concept of z-ordering, so you're likely to have issues with that to

Comment: *"I tried to disable all drawing in the JLayeredPane, yet it still draws the grey background that is visible. I don't know where that background is coming from."* - It's likely coming from the applet itself

Comment: AWT components might not have z-ordering, but the Applet is inside a `JLayeredPane`, which does. If it _is_ coming from the Applet itself, surely nothing can be done about this?

Comment: BUT, AWT components won't honour the z-ordering the `JLayeredPane` is trying to apply to it, because the `JLayeredPane` is simply changing the order in which the components are painted, BUT, AWT components will tend to paint themselves on top of everything else. This is why it's general discouraged to mix AWT and Swing components

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) I ended up using reflection to subclass the `Applet`, and paint my overlay using the applet's own `paint()`.

Comment: @MadsPH sorry for commenting on a super old post, but do you have an example of being able to do that handy? I've been stuck on this for hours now.